# Push a string into an array attribute in dynamodb table without duplicacy

Tags: vue.js, amazon-dynamodb

I have a company table with email ID array as one of the attributes. I need to push new emails into the array only if it doesn't exist in the array.

As example, I have an array of ["one", "two"] and if I pass ["one", "three"], the updated attribute value has to be ["one", "two", "three"] and not ["one", "two", "one", "three"].

Now, I'm thinking of querying the array first and then check for duplicacy, update the array and pass the updated array back to the database.

Is there any easier way to execute this, as I'll have to query multiple items and update all those items' email attribute and then pass those back to the database.

I'm using Vue and dynamodb.

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB has a special "set of strings" attribute type, with an operation of adding a value to it without duplications. 
Make sure you are not using a "list", where such duplicity does happen.